# GSheets Script, copy values only (because some cells are blank but contain conditional formulas)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I really hope someone can help me out.  My issue is that everything copies over fine, but some origin cells which show blank, actually have conditional formulas in them.  If they get copied as the script is now, the copied cells look blank, and have no formula, but I have to manually delete the values (which I can't see) to run the script again and have it put them in the correct rows.  Does that make any sense?  I think copying the values only initially will fix the problem?

```
function showAlert() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

var result = ui.alert(
 'Please confirm',
 'Ready to submit this data?',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

// Process the user's response.
if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
// User clicked "Yes".

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var source = sourceSheet.getRange("B5:I");

var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
if (lastRow) destSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form');
sheet.getRange('D5:I').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('F2').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('F3').clearContent();

ui.alert('Success!.');
} else {
// User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results and no formulas.

```
source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1));
```

should give you the array of values with no formula complications.